# Is it possible to generate a statically typed object based on function parameters?

Tags: typescript

I think it's impossible, but I'd like to make sure first.

I'm trying to create a statically typed params object for Intellisense, based on the string parameter passed in a function:

```
type Query = {
    _def: {
        params: Record<string, string> // what to put here?
    }
    params: (name: string) => Query;
}

const queryBuilder = (def: Query["_def"]): Query => {
    return {
        _def: def,
        params: (name) => {
            const innerDef = {
                ...def,
                params: {
                    ...def.params,
                    [name]: undefined as unknown as string // here just to save the type
                }
            }
            return queryBuilder(innerDef);
        }
    }
}

const c = queryBuilder({} as Query["_def"]);
const d = c.params("hello").params("world");
d._def.params; // should Intellisense hello and world
const e: typeof c._def.params = {} // should throw error saying hello and world are required
```

`Record<string, string>` doesn't provide Intellisense or errors. I can't do const assertions since there's nothing to assert. Is there anything else I'm not thinking of?

Edit: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: @jcalz sorry about that, playground added in post.

Comment: Your playground link doesn't demonstrate what you want it to; you are accessing `c._def.params` which is going to be empty no matter what; perhaps you meant you should be writing `const d = c.params("hello").params("world");` followed by `d._def.params` maybe?  If so, please fix it. ...

Comment: ... and then please add the code as plaintext in the question also; a playground link is nice, but it's not sufficient by itself.

Comment: ... and finally, is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w25M8W) what you're looking for?  If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `Query` to keep track of the keys inside its `_def.params` property, it should be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type parameter `K` corresponding to the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of these keys.  It could look something like this:

```
type Query<K extends string = never> = {
    _def: {
        params: Record<K, string>
    }
    params: <L extends string>(name: L) => Query<K | L>;
}
```

So a `Query<K>` has a `def.params` property of type `Record<K, string>`, using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) to represent an object type with `string`-valued properties at the keys in `K`.  Note that I've made `K` [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), which can be considered the "empty union".  So `Query` with no type argument is the same as `Query<never>`, which has a `_def.params` property without any known keys.

Note that the `params` property is itself a generic function; it is generic in `L`, the type of the `name` argument, and the return value is of type `Query<K | L>`, meaning it is a `Query` with both the `K` keys you started with, and the `L` key you just added.

---

Now we should give typings to `queryBuilder`.  In what follows I'm more concerned with guaranteeing type safety for *callers*, whereas I use some [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) inside the *implementation* in order to loosen things up that I know are fine but the compiler doesn't:

```
const queryBuilder = <K extends string = never>(
    def: { params?: Record<K, string> } = {}
): Query<K> => {
    return {
        _def: { params: {} as any, ...def },
        params: (name) => {
            const innerDef = {
                ...def,
                params: {
                    ...def.params,
                    [name]: "someString"
                }
            }
            return queryBuilder(innerDef) as any;
        }
    }
}
```

So `queryBuilder` is of type

```
declare const queryBuilder: <K extends string = never>(def?: {
    params?: Record<K, string> | undefined;
}) => Query<K>;
```

which means it accepts an [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters) `def` argument which is an object with an [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties) `params` property of generic type `Record<K, string>`.  And `K` defaults to `never`.  And it returns a value of type `Query<K>`.  So if you call `queryBuilder()` or `queryBuilder({})`, it should produce a `Query`. But if you call `queryBuilder({foo: "abc", bar: "def"})`, then it should produce a `Query<"foo" | "bar">`.

Let's try it out:

```
const c = queryBuilder({});
// const c: Query<never>
const d = c.params("hello").params("world");
// const d: Query<"hello" | "world">
console.log(d._def.params.hello.toUpperCase()) // "SOMESTRING"

const e = queryBuilder({ params: { foo: "abc", bar: "def" } }).params("baz");
// const e: Query<"foo" | "bar" | "baz">
console.log(e._def.params.bar.toUpperCase()) // "DEF"
```

Looks good.  The types of `c`, `d`, and `e` are as expected, and they match up with what happens at runtime.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAigrhATiAPAaShAHsCA7AEwGcojhEBLPAcygF4o8IA3JAPnqgG8AoKfqAH0CEAGYAubnwEywAQ0RyAtkUkAlCAGMA9ogLoANKXJVqbafwC+FqPMUrJKADKYc+Ysco02ACjzKISScASnoOeCRUDAAfKCc2AG4eax4dPDIoAEcEZAAhOAoAGxFETnRXXEISMi9aBiZWRF8bEQluWwVlIgB+dS1dfTQjGtMOS04ua2DJCOR0DjoOXhlECGA4RDwpGRlhMUkuDvtVbnG5Ejk8ECMAOjvWqEsDG1lOhyg-ANDF7Z2-tIyVCYiAAImIJi8-js7jdWs8oQijl0DpDEdD7mIbnYuvC0YiANr+JQQAC6kgARERtMSAMomGjk1GI6x4x5MlZrDZbbKRfJFEo+IFIMGiULnKCXEBJBEsgTWFIA4BQTScHl5ArFJA+SbBJIAej1yu06SVmhmOVQDXYqWNGQInE0WLeRB85IAFhBCoVtOTgk7jq6AO66Yq+-WGxVQAjmyIod2e73kqCxcnBxCh8wA7SFCA3b3UHwEG57UT+ro3D1e7Q3YDaACqYEgiAAwucID5gqEDVByTSAPIAWQAojSACpqACSADkAOKMm0mzCqi18zWIbVI96HUTabQUuQAI005KMB4UFNaSfGlj92JUrrPAC8wzxu5HArALXGdz7kz2z4gSYpk+5KZra2a5vmPi5iWZYqDcAE1vWjZIK2RDtp2UDduSIJDgAYoyQA)